# Moving files between two drives remotely

Tags: debian, sftp, smb, remote-management

Any ideas on a OS X app or protocol that would let me easily move files between say...

```
/home/user/Downloads
```

and

```
/media/user/External
```

my attempts so far trying to use SFTP or SMB haven't worked.  The Debian server doesn't seem to clue in these are both paths on its system and that it should be using MV instead of downloading to the client and reuploading.

Comment: I don't quite understand, I'm afraid. What's wrong with `mv`? You should clarify what's the Debian server in your case, what “haven't worked” means and what you mean by “remote management”.

Comment: It ought to be possible to do this through SFTP. It'd be nice to know exactly how you tried to do it through sftp, and what error messages you got.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scp, which is SSH copy

```
scp <path to file> <IP dest>:<path to dest dir>
```

Comment: You do not need to have the IP of the source machine if you are already on it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use "*ssh remote execution*":

```
$> ssh user@debianserver mv /home/user/Downloads/file_xy /media/user/External
```

For ease of use add the local `ssh` public key to the known keys on the Debian server, so you don't have to enter the password for the account `user` every time:

```
$> ssh-copy-id user@debianserver
```

Comment: Did that solve your problem?